# python-3.x,ipython3,pyqt5 How to link ipython3 to pyqt5 on startup?

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, pyqt5

I just noticed, when I was importing a file from my project I'm working on, that ipython3 is a little bit confused, because the file imports pyqt5 stuff.
Installed are both pyqt4 and 5, because have to use older versions from colleagues, who didn't upgrade their stuff yet.

My projects use pyqt5 so, **how do I link ipython3 qtconsole --pylab=qt& to pyqt5 on default?**

The error message was:

```
  2 
  3 import sys, os, math, shutil, re
----> 4 from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
  5 from ui_IMEX import Ui_IMEX
  6 

RuntimeError: the PyQt5.QtCore and PyQt4.QtCore modules both wrap the QObject class
```

which I interpret as pyqt4 is connected on default... because it's there.

Cheers,
Christian

Comment: I think `qt` is hardcoded to PyQt4; try using `--pylab qt5`

Comment: I tried that but no luck. I read the documentation about ipython and it is said that you can give the kernel options specifying what gui base you want to use. You even can use a config file collection, which I tried, too, but it didn't work either. error message: The 'pylab' trait of an IPKernelApp instance must be any of ['tk', 'qt', 'wx', 'gtk', 'osx', 'inline', 'auto'] or None, but a value of 'qt5' <class 'str'> was specified.

Comment: on the following page: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/options/kernel.html you can view the available options... they differ from what is given by the error message

Comment: Is there a difference between `--pylab=qt` and `--pylab=qt4`? That is, does `from PyQt5 import QtCore` produce the same error with both?

Comment: yes it does: [IPKernelApp] The 'pylab' trait of an IPKernelApp instance must be any of ['tk', 'qt', 'wx', 'gtk', 'osx', 'inline', 'auto'] or None, but a value of 'qt4' <class 'str'> was specified.
That's because a version number is not provided. I'm using the defaul ipython3 version of ubuntu's trusty branch.

Comment: It may lie in ipython3's version of 1dev...

Answer (score 0):

Till yesterday I tried to figure out how to get ipython (versions 2.3.1 and 3.xdev) to accept --pylab=qt5 (or similar: qt5agg, qt5Agg) but no luck. If one takes a look at the documentation the kernel directives mention them but the code doesn't. I noticed that some parts aren't even python3 ready and having issues with hte print() statements by lacking the brackets.

For support, I'm adviced to look here but it seams that it isn't any issue here and the once who tried to help aren't working with that versions or didn't get that deep into ipython to come across.

It is damm onerous having to start and stop the program I'm working on just to see that it's not doing what I want. Debugging that way is most unpleasant and that's why iypthon is in so much use for developing.

So, aren't there any more ideas how to fix that?

Comment: What error message do you see with `--pylab=qt5`? The backends it should accept are defined [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/pylabtools.py#L16), and qt5 was [added](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/6587) to both 3.0.dev and 2.3.

Comment: As you see in the comments above:  [IPKernelApp] The 'pylab' trait of an IPKernelApp instance must be any of ['tk', 'qt', 'wx', 'gtk', 'osx', 'inline', 'auto'] or None, but a value of 'qt4' <class 'str'> was specified.
But I got it know, I successfully downloaded everthing newly with git instead of svn and version 3.0.dev does what I want.

Comment: Great. Where did you get it from svn, though? IPython hasn't kept its source in svn for several years.

Comment: I just checkt 2.3.1 from the new download. still the same. Doesn't accept qt5-statements only qt and than it's qt4. But that's fine with me since 3.0.dev ist working.

Comment: I did the svn checkout from the gitoriouspage. On the right side it says: Subversion checkout URL

You can clone with HTTPS, SSH, or Subversion.
Because that caused soem errors in the past, I thought doing a clean installation with git. Was the right decision. If irritating errors occur, go back and do it again...

Comment: Now I'm thoroughly confused. IPython has never used gitorious, and as far as I know gitorious doesn't offer svn. Can you give me a link to this page? The official IPython repository is [on Github](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/).